# JSON.parse not working with knex where clause

Tags: node.js, knex.js

I'm using knex to create dynamic delete function.

Edit: The function is called from a GraphQL mutation and the tableName and whereClause are both Strings. In the edited code below I'm overwriting the whereClause for testing and demonstration purposes.

```
export const deleteRecords = async (tableName, whereClause) => {
  try {

    // Edit: testing with json string
    const whereClauseString = JSON.stringify('{id: 1000}');
    console.log(whereClauseString); // outputs "{id: 1000}"

    const whereClauseObject = JSON.parse(whereClauseString);
    console.log(whereClauseObject);
    console.log(whereClauseString); // outputs {id: 1000}

    await connection
      .from(tableName)
      .where(whereClauseObject)
      .del()
      .then(count => {
        const successMessage = `SUCCESS: ${count} records deleted from ${tableName}.`;
        console.log(successMessage);
      });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```

However, I get this error:
"SyntaxError: Unexpected token i in JSON at position 1"

Edit: After using `JSON.stringify` on the incoming json string, I now get the following error

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: The operator "undefined" is not permitted

For some reason it seems like `JSON.parse` is not creating an object that is supported by knex

Comment: Your json seems not valid. Did you try to print it and check if it's a valid json on something like https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string `'{id: 1000}'`, is not JSON. JSON does not have unquoted keys. Correct would have been `'{"id": 1000}'`.

```js
JSON.parse('{id: 1000}');
```

This cannot be parsed as JSON because of the `i` in position 1, where a double quote is supposed to be.

Chrome says *"SyntaxError: Unexpected token i in JSON at position 1"* in this situation, Firefox says *"SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data"*.

What to do?

1. Don't build JSON by hand. Always use `JSON.strigify()` or similar and build it from a data structure.
2. Separate your concerns. The function that runs the query should not also be the one that parses the JSON. That's needlessly constraining, because you are forced to pass in JSON even when you already have an object at hand: You would need to call `deleteRecords('table', JSON.stringify(myData))` just so that `deleteRecords()` can immediately call `JSON.parse()` again. `deleteRecords()` should expect an object as input. Parsing any JSON into is supposed to be the caller's task.
3. Make sure you use `await` when you use `async`. Never use the one without the other.

Better:

```
export const deleteRecords = async (tableName, whereClause) => {
  try {
    const count = await connection.from(tableName).where(whereClauseObject).del();
    const successMessage = `SUCCESS: ${count} records deleted from ${tableName}.`;
    console.log(successMessage);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: Great points. For point 2, this function is called directly from a graphql api, so a string will always be passed in. I guess I could have two separate functions and have this function call those two functions, but that is still combining two concerns

Comment: @navig8tr Shouldn't the GraphQL parse the JSON for you, then? Could it be that you're double-encoding?`

Comment: The GraphQL mutation accepts  two strings, the tableName and the whereClause. The whereClause will look like this: "{id: 1000}".

Comment: @navig8tr I'm not terribly familiar with GraphQL, but that seems a bit weird to me. GraphQL is all JSON, why would it require a string instead of an object in one place? Have you tried using an object instead of a string in the `whereClause`?

Comment: The requests are JSON but the parameters are passed in as strings

Comment: @navig8tr that's... well at least it's worth double-checking.

Comment: I tried changing the parameter type to object but it gives an error. This is how I make the API call
`mutation {
    deleteRecords(tableName: "test_table", whereClause: "{test_id: 1}") {
      statusCode
      message
      deletedRows
      error
    }
  }`

Comment: @navig8tr Ok, as I said, there are no unqutoted keys in JSON, so `"{test_id: 1}"` is not gonna work.